# How to clear the historial of irb using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, irb

I need to clear the historial of  irb interactive ruby

Can you help me?

When write irb in my console of Ubuntu 12.04 this error is displayed

Where is saved the historial de irb ?

Code

```
trabajo@fernando:~$ irb
load error: /home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/.irbrc
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/home/trabajo/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-     p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/.irbrc:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `load'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `run_config'
/home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/init.rb:19:in `setup'
```

irb(main):001:0>

Full File

```
# This is the common irbrc file used by all rvm ruby installations.
# This file will be overriden every time you update rvm.

# Turn on completion.
begin
  require "readline"

  require "irb/completion" rescue nil

  # Turn on history saving.
  # require "irb/ext/save-history"
  # IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".irb-history")

  # Use an alternate way to on history saving until save-history is fixed.
  #
  #   bug:   http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1556
  #   patch: http://pastie.org/513500
  #
  # This technique was adopted from /etc/irbrc on OS X.
  histfile = File.expand_path(".irb-history", ENV["HOME"])

  if File.exist?(histfile)
    lines = IO.readlines(histfile).collect { |line| line.chomp }
    Readline::HISTORY.push(*lines)
  end

  Kernel::at_exit do
    maxhistsize = 100
    histfile = File::expand_path(".irb-history", ENV["HOME"])
    lines = Readline::HISTORY.to_a.reverse.uniq.reverse
    lines = lines[-maxhistsize, maxhistsize] if lines.compact.length > maxhistsize
    File::open(histfile, "w+") { |io| io.puts lines.join("\n") }
  end

rescue LoadError
  puts "Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.\nYou may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.io/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries."
end

# Calculate the ruby string.
rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
  (
    ENV['GEM_HOME'] &&
    path = ( File.realpath(ENV['GEM_HOME'].to_s) rescue nil ) &&
    ( path = $1 if path =~ /(.+)\/$/ ; true ) &&
    path.split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first
  ) ||
  ("#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}" rescue nil) ||
  (RUBY_DESCRIPTION.split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p') rescue nil ) ||
  (`ruby -v` || '').split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p')

# cut ruby- ... everyone knows it's ruby
rvm_ruby_string = $1 if rvm_ruby_string =~ /^ruby[- ](.*)/

# Set up the prompt to be RVM specific.
@prompt = {
  :PROMPT_I => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ",  # default prompt
  :PROMPT_S => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n%l> ", # known continuation
  :PROMPT_C => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n > ",
  :PROMPT_N => "#{rvm_ruby_string} :%03n?> ", # unknown continuation
  :RETURN => " => %s \n",
  :AUTO_INDENT => true
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT] ||= {}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:RVM] = @prompt
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :RVM if IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] == :DEFAULT

# Load the user's irbrc file, if possible.
# Report any errors that occur.
begin
  load File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".irbrc") if File.exist?("#{ENV["HOME"]}/.irbrc")
rescue LoadError => load_error
  puts load_error
rescue => exception
  puts "Error : 'load #{ENV["HOME"]}/.irbrc' : #{exception.message}"
end
```

Comment: It looks like you have invalid code in your `.irbrc` file on line 45... Could you post that file?

Comment: this path   /home/trabajo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/.irbrc ?

Comment: Yes, post the contents of that file please.

Comment: # This loads some niceties for irb, courtesy of rvm.
# It also loads your custom ~/.irbrc if it exists.
# If you want to customize the irbrc for ONLY this version of
# ruby then edit this file. It will only be deleted if you do
# an "rvm install" over this ruby version.

if ENV["rvm_path"].nil?
  require File.join(ENV["HOME"], "irbrc")
else
  require File.join(ENV["rvm_path"], "scripts", "irbrc")
end

Comment: Can you add the full file to the question?

Comment: Oh shoot my bad. I asked you for the wrong file. :( Can you post this one? `/home/trabajo/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb`

Comment: I'm sorry. I am a nowbie in stackoverflow . Can I upload files?

Comment: That makes sense, because there's an error on the 45th line of the `irbrc.rb` file. If you post it I can help you figure out what's wrong with it, so you can keep your `irb` presets.

Comment: I copy the code in question?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can probably post the file from lines 1 to 45 in your question. You most likely don't need to do the whole file.

Comment: Friend This is the file

Comment: Can you post the output of `env | grep GEM_HOME` from your terminal? Check to see if this is the path to your gemset.

Comment: trabajo@fernando-:~$ env | grep GEM_HOME   
    GEM_HOME=/home/trabajo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481

Comment: Thanks Now working   rvm use 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked through my `irbrc.rb` and compared it to yours, and I noticed that everything is essentially the same, except for your lines 41 to 49. Perhaps it was manually edited by someone? Whatever the case, if you replace these lines:

```
rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
  (
    ENV['GEM_HOME'] &&
    path = ( File.realpath(ENV['GEM_HOME'].to_s) rescue nil ) &&
    ( path = $1 if path =~ /(.+)\/$/ ; true ) &&
    path.split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first
  ) ||
  ("#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}" rescue nil) ||
  (RUBY_DESCRIPTION.split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p') rescue nil ) ||
  (`ruby -v` || '').split(" ")[1].sub('p', '-p')
```

with these lines:

```
rvm_ruby_string = ENV["rvm_ruby_string"] ||
  ENV['GEM_HOME'].nil? ? `ruby -v`.match(/^([^ ]+ [^ ]+)/)[0].sub(/ /,'-') : ENV['GEM_HOME'].split(/\//).last.split(/@/).first
```

then your `irbrc.rb` file will match mine. Another you could probably do is update your ruby version, using `rvm get stable`.

Comment: Great . I update with rvm get stable and this problem was solved. Thanks JKen13579